# What was the song in Westworld S2E5?

Tags: soundtrack, westworld-tv

The episode was known for many remixes of contemporary songs such as "Paint it Black" by The Rolling Stones as a Japanese symphony remix (I was in love) and Akane’s dance as a traditional Japanese version of "C.R.E.A.M." by Wu-Tang Clan. [Source.](https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/962969/Westworld-season-2-episode-5-Shogun-World-song-CREAM-Wu-Tang-Clan-Ramin-Djawadi)

After the robbery, Maives offers to have a "civil meeting", and I thought the song leading up to the scene with everyone in Kimonos sitting was a remix of "Another One Bites the Dust" by Queen. Am I correct? If not, what song was it?

Comment: Music ID questions are off-topic.

Comment: @BCdotWEB That's not quite exactly true, though. And if anything, they are not and have never been closed with the ID question close-reason. Let's maybe not try to lose sight of the details here. They are off-topic if they amount to random trivia failing to point out a connection to the work at hand. If you think this applies to this question, go ahead and close-vote it as such. But let's cut down a little on blanket statements that aren't really true and misapplication of close-reasons.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I'm pretty sure it was you (if not, sorry) who closed the question that would have asked for the list of every rendition of songs on that show, which would have negated this question (and IMO is a perfect type of question to ask on a site that will update answers as they come into play). I fail to see how that one was trivia but this one isn't. Asking about just one song certainly is trivial though.

Comment: @Mazura Well, I didn't say this one isn't. I was advocating for not muddling up close-reasons and making blanket statements that are provably untrue. But I'm not sure if bringing some entirely different question with its very own problems into the mix is going to help with clearing up matters, though. For more information on how it actually works, though, feel free to consult [this discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1296/49) and the ones linked therefrom. I don't, however, remember the previous question you're talking about, relevance notwithstanding.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Having been edited by a moderator who wields a closehammer says otherwise. Unless you've changed your stance on when you use it? Again, I fail to see the difference between the two questions, other than different episodes. I can only presume the difference is in your prerogatives. Which is fine (as long as I can still blame you ;) for why there isn't just a single question that answers all of the music questions from Westworld in one fell swoop, for the rest of eternity.

Comment: Don't you want to have a dupe to point at and say, "Gah. There. Stop asking these questions." (because you *know* there'll be more...) *What are, and what is the significance of every song played under rendition in Westworld?*

Comment: @Mazura I would hesitate to draw conclusions about any broader stances or policies simply from the *lack* of moderator action. We don't actually *have* to unilaterally close every possible question. Sometimes it is interesting how edge cases develop. And yes, I consider this quite an edge case as the question adds quite a bit of motivation for asking it in order to justify it beyond idle trivia.

Comment: I will, however, *not* indulge in a discussion about some random unrelated question that I have zero recollection of and that got closed by whoever years ago. If that or any broder policy discussion is what you're looking for here, there's more appropriate venues for that.

Comment: vtc'd as trivia because just knowing the name of the song doesn't really add any appreciation to the show

Comment: And yet 4 people have again chosen an *entirely incorrect* close-reason. Frankly, I feel tempted to just reopen this if people can't be bothered to pick a proper close reason over just clicking the first item their mouse lands on.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson To me this just amounts to "I liked that song, what was it?" and that was my reason to close it, not a random click. Why is that song relevant? https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/are-identify-this-song-questions-on-topic

Comment: @Luciano Sure, and that's what the "trivia" close-reason is for. But people seem to read that meta discussion you link to and just pick the word "identification" out of it. I see we might need to work on that.